# python - removing date and time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

When using pandas I've imported my excel sheet, but it's a lot of effort to remove the timestamps every time.
I want to have a time like:
0.391772
Instead of:
20-9-2017  12:18:54,391772
Can someone help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this naive approach:

```
In [68]: '0.' + df.col.str.split(',').str[1]
Out[68]:
0    0.391772
1    0.123456
Name: col, dtype: object
```

PS assuming that the `col` column is of string/object dtype.

Demo:

```
In [77]: df
Out[77]:
                          col
0   20-9-2017 12:18:54,391772
1  11-11-2017 12:18:54,123456

In [78]: df['new'] = pd.to_numeric('0.' + df.col.str.split(',').str[1], errors='coerce')

In [79]: df.dtypes
Out[79]:
col     object
new    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: That seemed to work, my code now is:
x1 = pd.to_numeric('0.' + df1['x1'].str.split(',').str[1])
which seems to work pretty decently

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see that!